# Finding area between two graphs.

Tags: calculus

Find the area between the graphs of $ f(x) = (3x-2)^{10} $ and $ g(x) = 3x-2 $.

I just got the $ x's $ and can't continue.

$ x = \frac{2}{3} or \;x = 1 $

Comment: I assume you want to determine the area between two graphs at those intersection points, am I right?

Comment: Yeah that's right. It's definite integral question.

Comment: Just want to make sure of the bounds of integration.

Comment: since $g(x)>f(x)$ over $I=[\frac{2}{3},1$], you integrate $\int_I{[g(x)-f(x)]dx}=\int_I{g(x)dx}-\int_I{f(x)dx}$

Answer (score 1):

From where you left off, you determined the values of $x$ for the intersection points.  If we work out the substitution of those values, then we have

$$\begin{aligned}
f\left(\dfrac{2}{3} \right) &= \left(3 \cdot \dfrac{2}{3} - 2 \right)^{10} = 0 = g\left(\dfrac{2}{3} \right)\\
f(1) = g(1) &= 1
\end{aligned}$$

So the coordinates of those intersection points are $\left(\frac{2}{3},0 \right)$ and $(1,1)$.

*The graphs of the function $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%20=%20%283x%20-%202%29%5E10%20and%20y%20=%203x%20-%202%20for%202/3%20%3C%20x%20%3C%201).*

For the integral setup, we use the $x$-bounds (so we need to express the equation in terms of $x$).  Since the graph of $f(x) = (3x - 2)^{10}$ is below the graph of $g(x) = 3x - 2$, from the link I posted, we see that $f(x)$ is the lower function while $g(x)$ is the upper function within the interval $\frac{2}{3} \leq x \leq 1$.  For this case, the area of the region is

$$\begin{aligned}
\text{Area} &= \int_{\frac{2}{3}}^1 (\text{upper} - \text{lower})\,dx\\
&= \int_{\frac{2}{3}}^1 \left(3x - 2 - (3x - 2)^{10}\right)\,dx\\
&= \int_{\frac{2}{3}}^1 (3x - 2)\,dx - \int_{\frac{2}{3}}^1 (3x - 2)^{10}\,dx\\
&= \left.\dfrac{3}{2}x^2 - 2x - \dfrac{1}{3}\cdot \dfrac{(3x - 2)^{11}}{11}\right\vert_{x = \frac{2}{3}}^{x = 1}\\
&= \dfrac{3}{22}
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: How did you get $ \frac{1}{3} $ in the third step ?

Comment: This is found by substitution method.

Comment: How is that happened   ?

Comment: Set $u = 3x - 2$.  Then, $du = 3\,dx$.  Substitute $dx$ with $\frac{du}{3}$ and work out the integration via power rule

Comment: But why you didn't change the x to $ \frac{2+u}{3} $

Comment: There is no need to make such a substitution.  If you do so, you need to do this double times, which is unnecessary.

Comment: But you said substitute $ dx $ with $ \frac{du}{3} $ . How can you deal with $ x's $ in the integrand when you have a $ du$ Shouldn't it be all $ u's $ when you have $ du $

Comment: I edited the answer.  I set the integral for $3x - 2$ and $(3x - 2)^{10}$.  For the second integral, I used the substitution method instead of the first one.